# IMU gives wrong pitch angle after 70°

Tags: arduino, filter, imu, gyro, gyroscope

I am currently using [this library](https://github.com/aster94/SensorFusion), in particular the Mahony filter within it, for sensor-fusion on an IMU in my diploma project.

The library works great, but I have encountered a problem which only occurs for negative angles on the pitch axis.

The angles on the roll axis work fine, they go from -180° to 180°. The positive angle on the pitch axis also works fine and goes to 90°.

However, when I rotate the sensor in the opposite direction, the angle only goes to 70° and from there on it starts to count down.

Like so:

68°, 69°, 70°, 69°, 68°

I have been trying to resolve this issue for a week and haven't been succesful yet. The deadline for the first working prototype is coming closer and closer and I am not able to get accurate angles.

I am using the Mahony filter because I don't need Z orientations and therefore don't have a magnetometer.

If someone could  give me a hint into the right direction when it comes to solving this problem, I would be so thankful.

I am using an ESP32 as a microcontroller. I programm on PlatformIo in VSCode. The sensor is a LMS6DS3.

This is the code that I used for testing the IMU:

```
#include "SparkFunLSM6DS3.h"
#include "Wire.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#include "SensorFusion.h" //SF
SF fusion;

float gx, gy, gz, ax, ay, az, mx, my, mz;
float pitch, roll, yaw;
float deltat;
LSM6DS3 myIMU; //Default constructor is I2C, addr 0x6B

float DegtoRad = 0.0174532925199433f; //PI/180.0f;  
float angle=0;

void setup()
{

Wire.begin(21, 22);
Serial.begin(9600);
delay(1000); 
Serial.println("Processor came out of reset.\n");

myIMU.begin();

}



void loop()
{
ax=myIMU.readFloatAccelX();
ay=myIMU.readFloatAccelY();
az=myIMU.readFloatAccelZ();
gx=myIMU.readFloatGyroX()*DegtoRad;
gy=myIMU.readFloatGyroY()*DegtoRad;
gz=myIMU.readFloatGyroZ()*DegtoRad;

// now you should read the gyroscope, accelerometer (and magnetometer if you have it also)
// NOTE: the gyroscope data have to be in radians
// if you have them in degree convert them with: DEG_TO_RAD example: gx * DEG_TO_RAD

deltat = fusion.deltatUpdate(); //this have to be done before calling the fusion update
//choose only one of these two:
fusion.MahonyUpdate(gx, gy, gz, ax, ay, az, deltat);  //mahony is suggested if there isn't the mag and the mcu is slow
//fusion.MadgwickUpdate(gx, gy, gz, ax, ay, az, mx, my, mz, deltat);  //else use the magwick, it is slower but more accurate

pitch = fusion.getPitch()+9.8;
roll = fusion.getRoll();    //you could also use getRollRadians() ecc
yaw = fusion.getYaw();

Serial.print("Pitch:\t"); Serial.println(pitch);
Serial.println();

delay(5);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the lowest pitch angle that the device attained really is -70° and that the numbers you're receiving are actually correct? Remember that the lowest possible pitch angle is -90°, and the only time that that pitch angle will ever happen is when the device is pointed exactly straight down. If you try to point the device straight down, but your aim is off by 20°, then the software will report -70° if it is working correctly.

Comment: First verify whether the input to the sensor fusion is correct? In particular ax, ay, az.

Comment: I just noticed that you're adding an offset of 9.8° to the pitch value that SensorFusion gives you. That's not correct; you should remove that offset.

Comment: The lowest pitch Angle really is 70°. It works perfectly for the y-axis. The x-axis in positive direction also works. The problem only occurs on the negative x-axis. I've even measured the real tilt with a triangle ruler.